# Deleting any list that contains a negative number

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion, filtering

We had another nice question in a student activity today.

The increasing sequence of positive integers $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$ has the property that

$$
a_{n+2}=a_n+a_{n+1} \text{  for all } n\ge 1.
$$

If $a_7=120$, find $a_8$. (Solution: $a_8=194$.)

I found the `RecurrenceTable` command and wrote:

```
seqs=Table[RecurrenceTable[{a[2 + n] == a[n] - a[1 + n], a[1] == 120, 
   a[2] == k}, a, {n, 1, 7}], {k, 1, 120}]
```

This produced a list of lists that are possible answers. How can I delete any list from seqs that contains a negative number? And if necessary, how can I delete any list from seqs that is not decreasing?

Also, if anyone else sees a nice way of solving this problem using *Mathematica*, I'd love to see your contribution.

Comment: `DeleteCases[seqs, {___, _?Negative, ___}, {1}]`

Comment: `Cases[seq, {_?NonNegative ..}]`

Comment: I'm not sure, why this old question popped up, but I just saw it now. You are aware that your problem can be solved completely analytically without using any numerical calculations? If I'm not completely mistaken, you can give conditions how to create only positive sequences.

Answer (score 5):

Pick lists that don't contain negative number:

```
Pick[seqs, UnitStep @@@ seqs, 1]
```

> ```
> {{120, 72, 48, 24, 24, 0, 24}, {120, 73, 47, 26, 21, 5, 16}, 
>  {120, 74, 46, 28, 18, 10, 8}, {120, 75, 45, 30, 15, 15, 0}}
> ```

Pick non-increasing lists:

```
Pick[seqs, UnitStep @@@ -Differences /@ seqs, 1]
```

> ```
> {{120, 74, 46, 28, 18, 10, 8}, {120, 75, 45, 30, 15, 15, 0}}
> ```

And here is another approach to solve the problem:

```
sol = RSolve[{a[2 + n] == a[n] - a[1 + n], a[1] == 120, a[2] == a2}, a, n][[1, 1, -1]]
Reduce[{GreaterEqual @@ sol /@ Range@7, sol@7 > 0}, a2, Integers]
```

> ```
> a2 == 74
> ```

Comment: I understand this: `UnitStep[{120, 120, 0, 120, -120, 240, -360}]`, which gives this: `{1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}`. But I don't understand `UnitStep @@@ seqs`, which gives a list of zeros and four ones. I looked up `@@@` in the documentation and read `f @@@ expr replaces heads at level 1 of expr by f`. OK, so why does `UnitStep @@ {120, 120, 0, 120, -120, 240, -360}` return just a zero and why does `UnitStep @@ {120, 75, 45, 30, 15, 15, 0}` just return a 1.

Comment: @David Because [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html) owns two kinds of syntax, `UnitStep[x1, x2, ...]` represents the multidimensional unit step function which is `1` only if none of the $x_i$ are negative :)

Answer (score 4):

Candidate initial conditions:

```
mat = {{1, 1}, {1, 0}};
res = MatrixPower[mat, 7,{a, b}];
Reduce[res[[1]] == 120, {a, b}, Integers]
```

yields: C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLJgu.gif) [Element] Integers && a == 2 + 13 C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLJgu.gif) && b == 6 - 21 C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLJgu.gif)

```
fun[x_] := {2 + 13 x, 6 - 21 x}
```

The constraint of sequence of positive integers:

```
Reduce[Positive[fun[x]], x, Integers]
```

yields $x=0$ and is sufficient to guarantee and increasing sequence.

So, `a[n_, v_] := (MatrixPower[mat, n,v][[1]]`,

```
a[8, fun[0]]
```

Yields 194.

and just for fun:

```
Manipulate[
 tab = Table[fun[j], {j, 0, p}];
 ListPlot[Transpose[Table[{j, a[j, #]} & /@ tab, {j, 0, 9}]], 
  Joined -> True, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{7, 120}]}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"n", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(n\)]\)"}, 
  BaseStyle -> 12, GridLines -> {{8}, {194}}], {p, Range[5]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Use the "action" form instead: `MatrixPower[mat, 7, {a, b}]`

Comment: @J.M. Thank you I will edit when I get time.

Answer (score 3):

The following retains only `List`s that are strictly decreasing and contain no negative elements.

```
Cases[seqs, {z1_, z2_, z3_, z4_, z5_, z6_, z7_} /; z1 > z2 > z3 > z4 > z5 > z6 > z7 > 0]
(* {{120, 74, 46, 28, 18, 10, 8}} *)
```

or, more succinctly (see comments below),

Cases[seqs, {z__} /; Greater[z, -1]]

Additionally, the second code block in the Answer by [xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871/xzczd) can be modified readily to select only strictly decreasing non-negative `List`s.

```
Pick[seqs, UnitStep @@@ (-Differences /@ seqs - 1), 1]
(* {{120, 74, 46, 28, 18, 10, 8}} *)
```

There undoubtedly are other approaches.

Comment: Actually the first piece of code can be shortened to `Cases[seqs, {z__} /; Greater[z, 0]]` :)

Comment: @xzczd  A capability I did not know.  Thanks.  Probably, should be `Cases[seqs, {z__} /; Greater[z, -1]]`, though, because the question's criterion is non-negative.

Comment: To be more precise, the criterion of OP's question is non-negative, while the  original problem requires the sequence to be positive 囧.

Comment: The infix notation for `Greater` works with sequences too: `Cases[seqs, {z__} /; z > 0]`